# Set TextView with json parse when Button onClick

Tags: android, json

I want to make app if button clicked, the textview changed with json parse data. so, how i do that?

this is my code :

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        TextView tampilkan;
        Button btn1;
        String str_json = "{\"harga_jus\":\"{\"mangga\":\"5000\",\"jeruk\":\"3000\",\"apel\"4000\"}}";
        String copy;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            tampilkan = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tampil);
            btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
            try {
                JSONObject harga_jus = new JSONObject(str_json);
                JSONObject jus = harga_jus.getJSONObject("harga_jus");
                final String mangga = jus.getString("mangga");
                copy = mangga;
                btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        tampilkan.setText(copy);
                    }
                });
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: what problem do you have now?

Comment: 1.button click 2.parse data 3.change textview...  from these what you cannot figure out at this moment

Comment: Text view not change with json parse data

Comment: your json invalid .wrong format .http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

Comment: `\"apel\":\"4000\"` BTW which language is this `apel`

Comment: whatabout this json
 `{
    "harga_jus": {
        "mangga": "5000",
        "jeruk": "3000",
        "apel": "4000"
    }
}`

Comment: @Denny Kurniawan have fun :)

Comment: @PavneetSingh in indonesia we call apple fruit, apel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    final TextView tampilkan = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tampil);
    Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    String JSON = "{ \"harga_jus\": { \"mangga\": \"5000\", \"jeruk\": \"3000\", \"apel\": \"4000\" } }";
    try {
        JSONObject harga_jus = new JSONObject(JSON);
        JSONObject jus = harga_jus.getJSONObject("harga_jus");
        final String mangga = jus.getString("mangga");

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                tampilkan.setText(mangga);
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Yes, this is i want to know, you are my big hero. Thank you @IntelliJ Amiya

Comment: @DennyKurniawan Move ahead

Comment: of course, thank you for the spirit. @IntelliJ Amiya

Answer (score 3):

Just read logcat:

> org.json.JSONException: Unterminated object at character 17 of {"harga_jus":"{"mangga":"5000","jeruk":"3000","apel"4000"}}

Your json should be:

```
String str_json = "{\"harga_jus\":{\"mangga\":\"5000\",\"jeruk\":\"3000\",\"apel\":\"4000\"}}";
```

Comment: your  should be json is also invalid i guess :P

Comment: It's valid json. I've run that.

Comment: so when you run you remove the \ and use it or how you use that ?

Comment: Thank you @Divers i am wrong when add \"{\". Thank you for this

Comment: @Divers i have a personal request

Answer (score 2):

your json is not valid, replace your string with below :

```
String str_json = "{\"harga_jus\":{\"mangga\":\"5000\",\"jeruk\":\"3000\",\"apel\":\"4000\"}}";
```

Comment: add `{ "harga_jus": { "mangga": "5000", "jeruk": "3000", "apel": "4000" } }`

Comment: This right, my mistake is add \"{\". Thank you for this.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya No need to add anything. He posted already workable java code. The same as mine.

Comment: @Divers yes yes